# Simpler method to insert dataframe variable and name when creating many dataframes from raster type

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there a simpler way to designate new dataframe rows and rownames in the creation of a data frame from raster data?

```
rastA <- raster("rasterA.txt")
rastB <- raster("rasterB.txt") 
rastC <- raster("rasterC.txt") 
rastD <- raster("rasterD.txt") 
rastE <- raster("rasterE.txt")

dfA <- as.data.frame(rastA)
dfB <- as.data.frame(rastB)
dfC <- as.data.frame(rastC)
dfD <- as.data.frame(rastD)
dfE <- as.data.frame(rastE)

# Renaming column in dataframe
names(dfA)[1] <- 'values'
names(dfB)[1] <- 'values'
names(dfC)[1] <- 'values'
names(dfD)[1] <- 'values'
names(dfE)[1] <- 'values'

# Adding new column with classifier 'X'
dfA$type <- 'X'
dfB$type <- 'X'
dfC$type <- 'X'
dfD$type <- 'X'
dfE$type <- 'X'

df_AB <- rbind.data.frame(dfA, dfB)
df_AC <- rbind.data.frame(dfA, dfC)
df_AD <- rbind.data.frame(dfA, dfD)
```

With the final combined data frames fed into ggplot to generate various histogram and density plots.  This method (line by line) is easy enough, but I am wondering what efficiencies can be gained by using different methods.

Comment: It what this way is not simple?

Comment: Good point.  I guess when I have to do it for 30 rasters that I eventually rbind together into 3-10 different rasters, all with slightly different names.  I'll edit to expand to the true problem.

Comment: Why don't you stack your rasters then? Or directly add a layer to an existing raster?

Comment: Try it using `lapply`

Comment: I'm pretty new to R, but having to learn a lot quickly for academic reasons - if any of the suggestions that have been made could be applied, I would appreciate a small example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that simplifies part of this

```
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")  
fls <- c(f, f, f, f, f)
s <- stack(fls) * 1:5
names(s) <- LETTERS[1:5]

df <- as.data.frame(s)
df <- na.omit(df)
```

I would expect that for most plots, `df` is what you want to use, and that would not not need to create all these separate objects that you do. However, if that is what you want, perhaps do

```
x <- reshape(df, varying=colnames(df), v.name='values', timevar='group', times=colnames(df), direction='long', new.row.names=NULL)
# see http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/reshape.htm
rownames(x) <- NULL
x$id <- NULL
x$type <- 'X'

df_AB <- x[x$group %in% c('A', 'B'), ]
# etc
```